# A limit with no l'Hospital's rule - $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, logarithms, radicals

How do I find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$ without l'Hospital's rule? Or maybe I should ask: how do I prove it's equal to $0$?

Comment: **Hint:** Show by induction on $n\ge 10$: $\dfrac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$. I use $10$ just in case to make sure the base case works. There are many ways you can find a upperbound for $f(n) = \dfrac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: $$n=e^{\ln n}>\frac{\ln^3n}{6},$$ from the power series for $e^x$ and $\ln n\geq0.$